# How to remove serial numbers from delivery SAP?

Tags: sap-erp, bapi, function-module

I need to remove serial numbers from outbound delivery via standard FM-BAPI.
I used `DELETE_SERNR_LS` but this just changes the status of the serials.

Comment: What serial numbers do you mean?

Comment: we manage stock not with batches but with serials. When you post a GR, SAP create serial numbers (EM for 100 pieces = 100 serials). Serials are equipments, you can see them in EQBS and EQUI tables. In VL02N, you can add serials marking an item and clicking on "extras ==> serial numbers"